# How to save data getting from nested json in sql server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I am using following code to get the data from nested JSON.

```
 declare @json nvarchar(max)
set @json = '
[{

        "IdProject": "1",
        "Name": "Test Project",
        "SubSection": [{
            "IdStructure": "11",
            "IdProject": "1",
            "Name": "Test Structure",
            "Items": [{
                    "IdProperty": "111",
                    "IdStructure": "11",
                    "Name": "Test Property 2",
                    "DataType": 1,
                    "Precision": 0,
                    "Scale": 0,
                    "IsNullable": false,
                    "ObjectName": "Test Object",
                    "DefaultType": 1,
                    "DefaultValue": ""
                },
                {
                    "IdProperty": "112",
                    "IdStructure": "11",
                    "Name": "Test Property 1",
                    "DataType": 1,
                    "Precision": 0,
                    "Scale": 0,
                    "IsNullable": false,
                    "ObjectName": "Test Object",
                    "DefaultType": 1,
                    "DefaultValue": ""
                }
            ]
        }]
    },
    {
        "IdProject": "2",
        "Name": "Test Project",
        "SubSection": [{
            "IdStructure": "22",
            "IdProject": "2",
            "Name": "Test Structure",
            "Items": [{
                "IdProperty": "222",
                "IdStructure": "22",
                "Name": "Test Property 2",
                "DataType": 1,
                "Precision": 0,
                "Scale": 0,
                "IsNullable": false,
                "ObjectName": "Test Object",
                "DefaultType": 1,
                "DefaultValue": ""
            }]
        }]

    },
    {
        "IdProject": "3",
        "Name": "Test Project",
        "SubSection": [{}]

    },
    {
        "IdProject": "4",
        "Name": "Test Project",
        "SubSection": [{
            "IdStructure": "44",
            "IdProject": "4",
            "Name": "Test Structure"
        }]

    }
]';
select
    Projects.IdProject, Projects.Name as NameProject,
    Structures.IdStructure, Structures.Name as NameStructure,
    Properties.* 
from   openjson (@json) 
with
(
    IdProject int,
    Name nvarchar(100),
    SubSection nvarchar(max) as json
)
as Projects
outer apply openjson (Projects.SubSection)
with
(
    IdStructure int,
    Name nvarchar(100),
    Items nvarchar(max) as json
) as Structures
outer apply openjson (Structures.Items)
with
(
    IdProperty int,
    NamePreoperty nvarchar(100) '$.Name',
    DataType int,
    [Precision] int,
    [Scale] int,
    IsNullable bit,
    ObjectName nvarchar(100),
    DefaultType int,
    DefaultValue nvarchar(100)
)
as Properties
```

I am able to get data and it is working fine.

**Problem:**
How I can insert the data in the corresponding tables. I have three table which are in relationship:

1. Project
2. SubSection
3. Items

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use insert into Project select distinct IdProject, NameProject from (the query you run), and same with other two tables.

Comment: What's wrong with an `INSERT`?

Comment: Side note: `"SubSection": [{}]` looks wrong, it will result in a single empty row. It should be `"SubSection": null` or `"SubSection": [ ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to do this as separate insert statements:**

```sql
 declare @json nvarchar(max)
set @json = '
[{

        "IdProject": "1",
        "Name": "Test Project",
        "SubSection": [{
            "IdStructure": "11",
            "IdProject": "1",
            "Name": "Test Structure",
            "Items": [{
                    "IdProperty": "111",
                    "IdStructure": "11",
                    "Name": "Test Property 2",
                    "DataType": 1,
                    "Precision": 0,
                    "Scale": 0,
                    "IsNullable": false,
                    "ObjectName": "Test Object",
                    "DefaultType": 1,
                    "DefaultValue": ""
                },
                {
                    "IdProperty": "112",
                    "IdStructure": "11",
                    "Name": "Test Property 1",
                    "DataType": 1,
                    "Precision": 0,
                    "Scale": 0,
                    "IsNullable": false,
                    "ObjectName": "Test Object",
                    "DefaultType": 1,
                    "DefaultValue": ""
                }
            ]
        }]
    },
    {
        "IdProject": "2",
        "Name": "Test Project",
        "SubSection": [{
            "IdStructure": "22",
            "IdProject": "2",
            "Name": "Test Structure",
            "Items": [{
                "IdProperty": "222",
                "IdStructure": "22",
                "Name": "Test Property 2",
                "DataType": 1,
                "Precision": 0,
                "Scale": 0,
                "IsNullable": false,
                "ObjectName": "Test Object",
                "DefaultType": 1,
                "DefaultValue": ""
            }]
        }]

    },
    {
        "IdProject": "3",
        "Name": "Test Project",
        "SubSection": [{}]

    },
    {
        "IdProject": "4",
        "Name": "Test Project",
        "SubSection": [{
            "IdStructure": "44",
            "IdProject": "4",
            "Name": "Test Structure"
        }]

    }
]';
```

```sql
insert Project
  (Id, Name)
select
    p.IdProject, p.Name
from   openjson (@json) 
with
(
    IdProject int,
    Name nvarchar(100)
) as p;

insert SubSection
  (Id, IdProject, Name)
select
    s.IdStructure, p.IdProject, s.Name
from   openjson (@json) 
with
(
    IdProject int,
    SubSection nvarchar(max) as json
) as p
cross apply openjson (p.SubSection)
with
(
    IdStructure int,
    Name nvarchar(100)
) as s;

insert Items
  (Id, IdStructure, NameProperty, DataType, [Precision], [Scale],
   IsNullable, ObjectName, DefaultType, DefaultValue)
select
   i.IdProperty, s.IdStructure, i.NameProperty, i.DataType, i.[Precision], i.[Scale],
   i.IsNullable, i.ObjectName, i.DefaultType, i.DefaultValue
from   openjson (@json) 
with
(
    SubSection nvarchar(max) as json
) as p
cross apply openjson (p.SubSection)
with
(
    IdStructure int,
    Items nvarchar(max) as json
) as s
cross apply openjson (s.Items)
with
(
    IdProperty int,
    NameProperty nvarchar(100) '$.Name',
    DataType int,
    [Precision] int,
    [Scale] int,
    IsNullable bit,
    ObjectName nvarchar(100),
    DefaultType int,
    DefaultValue nvarchar(100)
)
as i
```